# Let $ \ \large f_k \ $ are harmonic on a Unit Disc $ \ D \ $

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $ \ \large f_k \ $ are harmonic on a Unit Disc $ \ D \ $. Show that no linear combination of these $ \large \ f_k  \ $ can be **Negative** on $ \ \partial D \ $ and **positive** at some point in the Interior of $ \ D \ $.

( **Hint:** Cauchy Integral formula, Maximum-minimum principle )

**Answer:**

Given  $ f_k \ $ are harmonic .

By Maximum - Minimum Principle , $ \ f_k \ $ attains its maximum on Boundary $ \partial D \ $.

Thus $ f_k \ $ can not be positive at Interior of $ D \ $ and Negative value on boundary $ \partial D \ $.

Thus the linear combination of these $ f_k \ $ also can not assume positive value in the interior of $ D \ $ and Negative value at the boundary $ \partial D \ $.

**Am I right ?**

**Is there any help?**

Answer (score 1):

Easy fact
Let $$F =\sum a_kf_k$$ be any finite linear combination of $f_k$ 
then is easy to see that $F$ is Harmonic too.

Therefore it archives its maximum and its minimum on $\partial D$

So if $$F\ge 0 ~~\text{on}~\implies \min_D F\ge \min_{\partial D}F\ge0 $$

Hence $F$ **cannot be Negative on  ∂D  and positive at some point in the Interior of  D**

Therefore such linear combination does not exists